# HR con texto centrado

Tags: html

estoy haciendo pruebas pero no lo logro, necesito que aparezca un hr y dentro de él un texto centrado, algo así como la foto a continuación.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMZTm.jpg

Comment: Por favor muéstranos (editando la pregunta y agregando el código) lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 2):

Primero: HR es (normalmente) una linea horizontal que (normalmente) ocupa todo el ancho del bloque. Por lo tanto no puedes poner algo "dentro" de él.

Segundo: lo anterior en realidad es impreciso. HR es, [semánticamente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr), una separación entre párrafos. Visualmente, suele representarse como una línea horizontal, pero eso no es esencial ni necesario. (De hecho, eso es una propiedad de su [estilo default](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css), y, por supuesto, puede ser cambiado via css)

Si lo que quieres es tener lo que muestras en la foto, pues acaso te convenga directamente meter todo como una imagen.

Si no, puedes jugar con spans o divs, pero debes ajustar los tamaños (y cuidar qué pasa cuando el ancho de la pantalla se reduce). Por ejemplo:

```css
.linea {
  margin:0px 20px;
  width:90px;    
  border-top:1px solid #999;
  position: relative;
  top:10px;
  float:left;
  }

.leyenda {
  font-weight:bold;
  float:left;
 }
```

```html
<div style="width:400px;margin:auto;">
<div class="linea">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="leyenda">Portafolio</div>
<div class="linea">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```